# Write/export envelope label to an external file

Tags: letters, envlab

The following example was taken from documentation found at [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.296.648&rep=rep1&type=pdf) url on page 4, figure 1.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[personalenvelope]{envlab}
\makelabels
\address{%
Joe Casanova\\1 Lambda Street\\Anyplace, NY 12345}
\signature{Joe}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
Mary McKeen\\2 Alpha Street\\Otherplace, NY 12346}
\opening{Dear Mary:}
I love only you
\closing{With love,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

If Joe wishes to send his heartfelt message to his one and only, true love both electronically, and by post, would there be a way for him to have the envelope label exported to a separate file?

The ideal workflow would be as follows:

1. Compose letter in .tex file (envelope labels are generated automatically therein)
2. Compile document, two .pdf files are generated, one is letter only, one is envelope
3. Attach letter only .pdf to email, send
4. Open letter only .pdf, print on appropriate paper
5. Open envelope only .pdf, print on envelope
6. Seal envelope, mail.

Any comments/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Surely a letter of this kind should be hand written?

Comment: If you really want to automate love, though, I would use a script rather than trying to do it within TeX itself. That is, write the `.tex` file and then run the script to generate the various PDFs, print whatever (no need to open it) etc. You couldn't script steps 1 or 6 but the rest should be pretty straightforward. At least on GNU/Linux or other Unix-type system.

Comment: I'd use [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) for this.  With your file (called, say `letter.pdf`), I'd write: `pdftk letter.pdf burst output letter-%d.pdf`.  That splits a multi-page PDF into separate files for each page, so if you write really long love letters, you'd need to use a slightly different command.  Same principle, though.

Comment: I passed these comments along to Joe; he is most appreciative.  Joe did end up pursuing an implementation involving pdftk.  Specifically, he opted to write a script in which the `burst` command is used.  He then used the `cat` command to collate all but the last page and `output` to a file, `letter.pdf`.  The last of the files generated from the burst is renamed `envelope.pdf`.